# Client Side React JS post request

Tags: javascript, axios

I am trying to execute a post request to a server running on the same machine, from client rendered react application but I am getting a bunch of errors.

I have enabled a browser plugin that can mitigate the CORS issue, I have also put a temporary filter on the server-side to pass the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *`.

I have no issue with `GET` requests on that matter. I am able to query the API just fine.

Unfortunately, this is not the case with `POST` (Please excuse my ignorance if the answer is obvious - is it even possible to make client-side post requests?)

bellow is the function that does the request and expects the result on the console.

```js
    const postAddCategory = () => {

        const myHeaders = {host: "localhost:3000"};

        const body = {"productCategoryName": categoryName, "enabled": enabled};

        const config = {
            headers: myHeaders
        };
        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/products/categories/category/add", body, config)
            .then(r => console.log(r.data))
    }
```

The errors:
[image]

The interesting fact is that the request is not reaching the API at all.

I have tried several variations on the call with different headers, excluding the host header, since it is complaining about that as well. I have tried with the fetch API. No luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**edit**

Even though the call is **not** reaching the API,

the API is build in Java (Spring Boot)
and the filter is the following:

```java
@Component
public class ForDevelopmentOnlyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                         ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

The above works because the `GET` request were complaining with CORS related errors before its addition.

Comment: Can you show the server-side code that enables CORS?

Comment: can you try to add these two lines, `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');` and `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');` in your backend

Comment: It is pretty evident from the error message that the violation of CORS policy is not due to the origin, but one of the request headers - 'Content-Type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Root cause of the problem is shown by the error -

***Content-type is not allowed by Access-control-allow-headers***

This problem can be fixed by explicitly adding the following header to the server:

**'access-control-allow-headers : content-type' on the server.**

**Reference:**

AJAX requests from browser follow these 3 step process:

**Step 1:  (Pre-flight request)**

Browsers asks the server for permission, using the **'HTTP OPTIONS'** request. This is also called the 'pre-flight' request.

**Step 2: (Server tells the options)**
Server responds to pre-flight request and indicates to the browser what is allowed.

**This response contains following information:**

- Allowed origins (Example: xyz.com, * )
- Allowed methods (Example: get, post, delete, put ...)
- Allowed headers (Example: authorization, content-type, *)

**Step 3:**
Browser checks the options provided by the server and makes the actual AJAX request, only if the options provided by the server allow it.

**More information:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers